# How to use like and in together in sql statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WHERE SUBSTR(NAME, 1, 1) LIKE IN ('k', 'l', 'b')
```

If I use this code, I get an error

> ORA-00936: missing expression

There seems to be no error logically, but I am wondering which part of the code above is wrong.

I'm also curious about a way to replace `LIKE IN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `LIKE` from your current `WHERE` clause leaves it valid:

```sql
WHERE SUBSTR(NAME, 1, 1) IN ('k', 'l', 'b')
```

It isn't clear from what you posted alone above why you think you need `LIKE` here.  If you wanted to express the above logic using `LIKE`, you could use:

```sql
WHERE NAME LIKE 'k%' OR NAME LIKE 'l%' OR NAME LIKE 'b%'
```

Note that if your version of SQL supports regex like, you could also use the regex pattern `^[klb]`.